# Implementing A Custom 2 Factor Authentication Mechanism In Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I've found a good [2 factor authentication library](https://github.com/glacasa/TwoStepsAuthenticator) on github that I like and I'm trying to integrate it into my Asp.Net Core project, but I'm having trouble finding what I need to do to achieve that.

I've got a custom UserStore implementing IUserStore and IUserTwoFactorStore (As well as a bunch of other interfaces) but those only show how to determine if the user actually has 2-FA enabled or not and set it, but not how to actually add and retrieve a custom provider.

I've got /can figure out all of the code I need to get the 2-FA working, it's just hooking it up that I'm stuck on.

I hope that I don't need to create a custom UserManager implementation, as that could potentially be a lot more work (Although I suspect it's the case - the following methods look promising GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(), GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(), VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync()).

Comment: This might be a good place to start: (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs) I have not looked at this in great detail, but is seems to have a descent example. Maybe you already found this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom version of the UserManager class, and only overrode the 3 methods I described above.

It seems to do the job and was pretty quick (I was originally worried that I'd have to implement/override all the methods, but realized once I started that that wasn't the case).